# Why was Bee Gees' Staying Alive sung in a high-pitched voice?

Tags: bee-gees

Why was Bee Gees' Staying Alive sung in a [high-pitched voice](https://youtu.be/ksJ8dtaxHR0)?

What was the singer trying to achieve by that?

What would have happened if the song had been sung in a [normal voice](https://youtu.be/UC1FQBAK8NY)?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+did+the+bee+gees+sing+falsetto&t=newext&atb=v239-1&ia=web

Comment: Because Barry Gibb was singing it?  It was kind of their style at the time.  If he'd sung it without falsetto or let Robin sing, it would sound . . . different.  You'd probably make different mixing choices to help a voice in a lower register stand out.

Maybe the best way to find out is find a karaoke version of the song and sing it without falsetto?

Comment: Thanks for the cover song link! Of course it will work in another vocal range, most good songs will. The falsetto voice has links to romantic songs like Doo-wop style, and sort of implies the cooing and sighing of love making, so it's sexy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does any artist do anything different from everyone else? Generally because they want to stand out in the crowd of other artists. Having some form of distinctive sound/trait/style helps in getting people to recognize you on the radio and selling your music. In principle a distinctive trait can be anything, but it's frequently something in the overlap between what the artist is good at and what is popular with the audience.

The Bee Gees falsetto apparently came about more or less by accident. The producer asked for harmonized background screaming for a recording, it was the first time Barry sang falsetto, and he discovered that he was good at it.

> “We found a new sound. I came up with a lot of new ideas to suit the falsetto,” Barry remembered. “Everybody was saying the same thing: ‘Do that falsetto again, do that falsetto again.’ It was fine for me; I was having a ball.”

And falsetto singing was already a thing:

> "[The producer] brought it out of us, you know we weren’t the first to sing in falsetto,” Maurice said. “We loved The Stylistics, The Spinners, The Delfonics. They were all falsetto lead singers,” he said, referencing top Black ensembles at the time.

So they went with falsetto singing because they were good at it, it gave a distinctive sound, and it was popular with their audience.

https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/bee-gees-trademark-falsetto-sound-030939258.html

Comment: Part of the 'trick' [also use by Green Gartside of Scritti Politti] is that the register isn't necessarily high; the trick is to stay in falsetto even when a singer would usually be back in chest voice. That's what makes it 'special'. It's not really hard to do, but it needs a bit of discipline & breathing technique to keep it up. [Background: I did all the original Pioneer Video Karaoke Bee Gees vocals, back in the 80s, so I spent quite some time perfecting the technique.]

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is just my opinion and I can give many reasons.

First of all he had a really good falsetto which he used perfectly to create a timeless hit and I wonder if we would have Mika or Scissor Sisters singing in that style if it wasn´t for that song.

Another factor is the originality. Most men sing with a baritone voice (like Bruce Springsteen) but it's rarer to see a man singing in falsetto, I can't recall a lead voice singing like that before them, I can think of the Beach boys but in that case the falsetto worked more as harmonization of the lead vocal.

Yet another factor is that such a high pitched voice will stand out in the mix much more easily without extra volume. Kind of like a violin in an orquestra.

Then it just feels right for a happy, uplifting disco song. If you notice Springsteen's version, it has a much more mellow feel to it. Great version but doesn't make me want to go crazy on the dancefloor.

Comment: There’s also the fact that most Bee Gees songs were sung the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The BEE GEES / Barry Gibb actually introduced a unique falsetto sound that is very difficult to emulate. Before their time,all falsetto sound were more stygmatized as a female-ish comical sound; then came the Philly Sound with the Stylistics, Blue Magic, etc..  and they were embraced more as a soulful, velvety-tailored for mellow ballads type of songs.
Then The Gibbs came in, and gave the sound the definitive musculine, kick-a$$, bombastic personification. And that's what made it refreshingly new , exciting & interesting
Of course Barry can also belt it out on the other end of the spectrum with smooth, airy, & silky ballads.
This era of their career was their 2nd Comeback. After their initial worldwide success of Mining Disaster, Massachusetts,Words, To Love Somebody, etc... they split for about 18 mos. and came back with How Can You Mend...(first US No.1 hit) & Lonely Days.
Then they started to struggle again. It was when they shifted to the more contemporary R&B sound with the album Main Course that placed them in the right direction. This was their 2nd Comeback with a different attitude this time.
And they soared out in the hyperspace of fame with the SNF soundtrack with their new/ re-invented sound which the  dearly loved.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the falsetto singers of that time were trying to compete with Eddie Kendrick’s of the Temptations.Eddie’s falsetto actually sounded fairly natural.Most falsetto’s could not match his natural sounding falsetto but they were pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

*The accepted answer is good, but it's worth adding some more context.*

The BeeGees had an entire other career before their falsetto hits. They were a 60s boy-band in the mode of the Beatles. The Jonas Brothers would probably be a good modern analogy. By the mid-70s their star had faded, and they were viewed as has-beens. They needed a new sound and style to set them apart from all the other worn-out Beatles clones.

Their comeback opportunity came with the new subgenre of disco music, which was pioneered--as was virtually every other major trend in American music--by Black Americans (specifically the gay Black underground dance scene of New York City). Along with taking on the disco sound, the re-imagined BeeGees also started singing in falsetto, another element associated almost wholly with Black groups (Frankie Valli being the main exception). Their success, as combined with the release of the movie *Saturday Night Fever,* helped break disco with the mainstream white audience, thus creating the international disco craze of the late 70s, and bringing the BeeGees a level of success that eclipsed their earlier fame. In other words, like Elvis before them, and Eminem after them, they became superstars as the chief white exponents of a (previously) Black musical style.